# How do I use MetalKit texture loader with Metal heaps?

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit, xcasset, mtktextureloader

I have a set of Metal textures that are stored in an Xcode Assets Catalog as Texture Sets. I'm loading these using `MTKTextureLoader.newTexture(name:scaleFactor:bundle:options)`.

I then use a `MTLArgumentEncoder` to encode all of the textures into a Metal 2 argument buffer.

This works great. However, the *Introducing Metal 2* WWDC 2017 session [recommends combining argument buffers with resource heaps for even better performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/601/?time=1384), and I'm quite keen to try this. According to the [Argument Buffer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/fundamental_components/gpu_resources/tracking_the_resource_residency_of_argument_buffers), instead of having to call `MTLRenderCommandEncoder.useResource` on each texture in the argument buffer, you just call `useHeap` on the heap that the textures were allocated from.

However, I haven't found a straightforward way to use `MTKTextureLoader` together with `MTLHeap`. It doesn't seem to have a loading option to allocate the texture from a heap.

I'm guessing that the approach would be:

- load the textures with `MTKTextureLoader`
- reverse-engineer a set of `MTLTextureDescriptor` objects for each texture
- use the texture descriptors to create an appropriately sized `MTLHeap`
- assign a new set of textures from the `MTLHeap`
- use some method to copy the textures across, perhaps `replaceBytes` or maybe even a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder`
- deallocate the original textures loaded with the `MTKTextureLoader`

It seems like a fairly long-winded approach, and i've not seen any examples of this, so I thought I'd ask here first in case I'm missing something obvious.

Should I abandon `MTKTextureLoader`, and search out some pre-MetalKit art on loading textures from asset catalogs?

I'm using Swift, but happy to accept Objective-C answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the method I outlined above seems to work. As predicted, it's pretty long-winded. I'd be very interested to know if anyone has anything more elegant.

```
enum MetalError: Error {
    case anErrorOccured
}

extension MTLTexture {
    var descriptor: MTLTextureDescriptor {
        let descriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
        descriptor.width = width
        descriptor.height = height
        descriptor.depth = depth
        descriptor.textureType = textureType
        descriptor.cpuCacheMode = cpuCacheMode
        descriptor.storageMode = storageMode
        descriptor.pixelFormat = pixelFormat
        descriptor.arrayLength = arrayLength
        descriptor.mipmapLevelCount = mipmapLevelCount
        descriptor.sampleCount = sampleCount
        descriptor.usage = usage
        return descriptor
    }

    var size: MTLSize {
        return MTLSize(width: width, height: height, depth: depth)
    }
}

extension MTKTextureLoader {
    func newHeap(withTexturesNamed names: [String], queue: MTLCommandQueue, scaleFactor: CGFloat, bundle: Bundle?, options: [MTKTextureLoader.Option : Any]?, onCompletion: (([MTLTexture]) -> Void)?) throws -> MTLHeap {
        let device = queue.device
        let sourceTextures = try names.map { name in
            return try newTexture(name: name, scaleFactor: scaleFactor, bundle: bundle, options: options)
        }
        let storageMode: MTLStorageMode = .private
        let descriptors: [MTLTextureDescriptor] = sourceTextures.map { source in
            let desc = source.descriptor
            desc.storageMode = storageMode
            return desc
        }
        let sizeAligns = descriptors.map { device.heapTextureSizeAndAlign(descriptor: $0) }
        let heapDescriptor = MTLHeapDescriptor()
        heapDescriptor.size = sizeAligns.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.size }
        heapDescriptor.cpuCacheMode = descriptors[0].cpuCacheMode
        heapDescriptor.storageMode = storageMode
        guard let heap = device.makeHeap(descriptor: heapDescriptor),
            let buffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer(),
            let blit = buffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()
            else {
            throw MetalError.anErrorOccured
        }
        let destTextures = descriptors.map { descriptor in
            return heap.makeTexture(descriptor: descriptor)
        }
        let origin = MTLOrigin()
        zip(sourceTextures, destTextures).forEach {(source, dest) in
            blit.copy(from: source, sourceSlice: 0, sourceLevel: 0, sourceOrigin: origin, sourceSize: source.size, to: dest, destinationSlice: 0, destinationLevel: 0, destinationOrigin: origin)
            blit.generateMipmaps(for: dest)
        }
        blit.endEncoding()
        buffer.addCompletedHandler { _ in
            onCompletion?(destTextures)
        }
        buffer.commit()
        return heap
    }
}
```